# Active button in my email using php

Tags: php

am trying to put a button in the email created with php so that when the user gets that email, they can click the button to delete a record in the database directly without leaving the email client or email window they are in.
is it possible and how do i achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Nope its not possible

Comment: You may send a link (a URL) with the message, when the user clicks it, it will call your script which will delete or do any other thing.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: which then fires up a browser and "leaves" the mail client. What OP wants is not possible

Comment: @MarcB that page may attempt to close itself afterwards. Could that suffice for OP?

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get I think is putting in a hyperlink to a web page which will automatically trigger the deletion when given the correct parameters. But it will still launch a web browser (and then a server-side script must run to do the deletion or whatever). And therefore you'll probably want to provide some feedback to the user on that page as well.

Comment: so there must be a redirect. using a link

Comment: @GoodJohn exactly. You can't directly include a HTML form in an email.

Comment: We need to actually solve the underlying problem rather than proposing something else that would work.

Comment: @KeralPatel nice try, but this particular problem is not actually solvable in the way the OP would have liked. Hence "the closest you can get..." in the answer. A workaround is appropriate when the desired solution is genuinely not achievable. P.S. Did you seriously go and trawl my answers from 4 years ago just to try and make a point in riposte to my comments on your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644025/include-file-outside-from-public-html/62645390#62645390)? Maybe if you spend more time you'll manage to find one where you can actually catch me out :-)

Comment: hehehe feels good to know the real reason. Thank you for elaborating on it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. At best your email will contain a link that will spawn a new window or tab that will access a page to delete the record.