# include file outside from public_html

Tags: php, include, public-html

Ι want to include a file  outside from public_html in php.

I placed a file outside from public_html and tried to include this file,  to a file that exists to public_html/myDirectory.

I tried this `include '../../myFile.php';` but it's not working.

Where am i wrong ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In what way does it fail?  Is there an error?  Unexpected output?  Something else?

Comment: Where _exactly_ is this file located?

Comment: myFile.php/public-html/ is the file that i want to include into public_html/myDirectory/MyFile.php

Comment: David is about mysql connection , i have this file outside from public_html with username and password

Comment: @jeriko, if the error you see is mysql connection error, there is no problem with the inclusion itself.

Comment: i think that with this code does not include myFile.php .The error that i get is "Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"Into myFile.php i have password and username.

Comment: jeriko, you need to do some further testing to see if the myFile.php is working properly. For example, add echo and/or debug statement in myFile.php and see if you can see the results.

Comment: At public_html i have the same file.And when i include this file into public_html/myDirectory/MyFile.php with this code include '../myFile.php'; i get no errors

Comment: @jeriko: The `include` operation makes no attempt to connect to a database.  If the error is that the code is failing to connect to the database, then the error is not on the `include` line.  Wherever you're trying to connect to a database, that's where the problem is occurring.

Comment: jeriko, do you correct permissions on the myFile.php?

Comment: Also, what happens if you change `include` to `require_once`?

Comment: perm 777.The code that is working - > https://pastebin.com/J7sL8vhb - When i try with ../ it's ok.The problem exists when i include  the file with password and username which is outside public_html with this ../../

Comment: so you think it's not finding the correct username and password? As kojow says, change include to require_once and see if you get an error. Also, the include could be working fine, but maybe the way you define the variables isn't, or something. hard to know without seeing that version of the code. BTW there's no need to paste code on other sites. Your question has an "edit" button, so you can use that to update your post with code, and you can use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
 to make it readable and neat.

Comment: ADyson, it is finding the correct username and password when i include the file that is into public_html folder.When i include the file that is outside from public_html folder it returns "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 1045 Debugging error: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)".The file that i want to include outside from public_html and the file i include from public_html are exactly the same.

Comment: As requested, did you change `include` to `require_once`, to check if it errors when you require the file (as opposed to just making it optional)? Please give a clear answer to that, it might be significant. The trouble with `include` is that it won't actually cause your script to fail if it can't find or open the file

Comment: require_once returns HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the real problem. (Obviously, for that to work, you need to have configured PHP to log errors to a file. Here's a guide to doing that if you need one: https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/)

Comment: @ADyson  here it is

Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/user/db.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/user/public_html:/tmp:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear:/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72) in /home/user/public_html/customers/login.php on line 4

Warning: require_once(/home/user/db.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/user/public_html/customers/login.php on line 4

Comment: Well there you go then. PHP is not allowed to open that file because it's outside the permitted area. Do you know what open_basedir does? If not, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir . So you'll need to change this setting before it can work.

Comment: But...why is it such a big deal? Moving the DB username and password outside public_html doesn't, by itself, make it more secure. (And the fact you've given it 777 permissions makes it less secure really.) No user of the website can ever see that data because it's in a .php file, and the source code will never be shown to them. If you really want to secure the password outside your code (which is still sensible for other reasons), then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php

Answer (score -1):

Use full fledged path like.

```
include("/home/hostusername/myFile.php");
```

Replace hostname with your hostusername.

Comment: This is not very practical for sites which can be deployed into different locations in different environments. Relative paths solve that problem. So this solution solves one problem but just creates another one instead.

Comment: Agreed it is not practical but without knowing full structure of his file system this is best I could come up with. Others have already suggested ../ and that is not working for the OP as he stated.

Comment: Well that means either the path is wrong (easy enough to correct if we knew the real path) or maybe actually the use of `include` (instead of `require`) is obscuring something like a permissions issue. We need to actually solve the underlying problem rather than proposing what is effectively a workaround which, as I've already said, creates other problems instead.

Comment: And I am waiting for the OP's full response to my questions before I can give a solution, because (as I hinted in my comment above) we do not yet possess all the necessary information :-)

Comment: If you check the latest comments on the main thread of the question now, you can see what the underlying issue turned out to be... :-)

Comment: Agreed. Looks like getting full info out from someone is the key. I know always more than one angle involved.

Answer (score -1):

`/` is absolute system path
to get your directory name use

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

where your file position the first folder use `/` only

```
include '/myfile.php';
```

The 2nd directory use file name

```
 include '/filename/myfile.php';
```

other wise use curl or file get

```
file_get_contents("/myfile.php"); //http://yoururl.com/myfile.php
```

update your main code include alternate

Comment: It seems pretty clear from the question that the file is _outside_ the normal document root. In fact, that's the entire point of the question...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but not sure how this update would help? It would be great if you explained it for everyone's benefit. As far as I can see now you're just proposing a hard-coded path which creates as many problems as it solves (particularly when deploying the site to different locations). Anyway have you been reading the comments above? The path itself not the issue, it's the permissions to that path.

Comment: Thanks for the further edit. But none of these help to deal with relative paths above the current one. And again, if you read the comments, this has nothing to do with the real problem anyway.

Comment: file_get_contents will return the source code as a string but it won't include it in the current script as executable code in the way that `include` or `require` does. And the example you've given still using hard-coded instead of relative paths. So it won't achieve what the OP wants. And even if it did, it still doesn't get round the permissions issue being discussed in the comments on the main question thread.